# Cannot load javascript module in rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to load a simple vue module in my layout application file
but the app is failing to load the module. I am using the webpacker gem with rails 5.1.1. and ruby version 2.3.3 
Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Potato</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'hello_vue' %> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The hello_vue.js  file (see code below) is located in the javascript/packs directory and it's importing a very basic hello.vue file also located the same directory:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hello'))
  const app = new Vue(App).$mount('hello')

  console.log(app)
})
```

I've tried to restart the rails server and the webpack-dev-server but nothing...
the app seems just to ignore the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've generated a controller Pages with an index action and now it's working...